# IdentityServer4 How can I redirect after login to the revious url page without registering all routes at IdP

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

As recommend I would have register the authorize callback url/redirect_url at IdP, which it works.

But what if a client using MVC app tries to access a page with an unauthorized state, will be redirect to idsrv login page.

The redirect_url is always (Home page entry point) as configured.

**To change this behavior I would have to register all possible routes at IdP.
That can not a be solution!**

On idsrv Login method I have tried:

`Login(string returnUrl)`

checking the value from `returnUrl` it gives `/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=...`

Shouldn't `returnUrl` have the url of the previous page? Like in a normal mvc app has..

I have tried to get Referer store it on session and then redirect..

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString()))
 {
      this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Referer", Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
 }
```

But that doesn't work Referer comes null...

I have checked what's coming on context from interation services

```
var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);
                        context.RedirectUri
```

And returns `/signin-oidc/` this is the automated way for returning (Home page entry point).

Any chance to get the previous url, so that the user can be redirect?

So what can I do else?

I'm using Hybrid flow to manage the following clients : mvc-app, classic-asp, web api

Comment: The return url is configured per client and by default in asp.net core its `/signin-oidc/` which is the handler uri for when the token gets sent back. If you change that uri to a different protected url, then you will have infinite loop unless you add your authentication logic.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius thanks for your reply, yes the url is configured per client, and that it's working perfectly. For example for a concrete client I could set a collection of possible routes to RedirectUris and that would make it work. But that isn't a option.. 
I'm searching for away to get the previous url where a client try to access, so that I can send the user back to same page. do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: I thought it works like that out of the box https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a677fd231e2f8e9d18749fc2a4761d1a724bc6c1/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L348 but if it doesnt you should be able to override this method and mess around with the final redirect uri

Comment: You need to handle it yourself. You can either create a session/cookie on your client and save the previous url where you'll send the user back when they are redirected. Or you could use an extra parameter during the request that would contain the final url.

Comment: @cheesemacfly thanks for your reply, it's hard to believe that feature it's not out of the box and I have to build that..  by reading the official documentation of login workflow http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html#login-workflow it talks about returnUrl like it should be the previous url where the user should be redirect to.. I'm I wrong? Do you have some sample where I can look at?

Comment: That's the returnUrl in this case comes from identity server and contains the information pertaining to the original request, like clientid, scope, extra parameters...I'll try to add an example later today

Comment: Thanks @cheesemacfly, yes the value that comes on `returnUrl` 
 is the callback to the client `/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=...` I'll be waiting your example, thanks again

Comment: How's your client setup, are you using owin, .net core or something else?

Comment: Clients: mvc-app and web api are the latest .net core 2, and server is also core 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of implementation allowing you to achieve what you want. Keep in mind that there's other ways of doing it.

All the code goes on your client, the server never knows anything about the end url.

First, you want to create a custom attribute that will be decorating all your actions/controllers that you want to protect:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp
{
    internal class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
              filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["oidc-returnUrl"] = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer?.PathAndQuery;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you are going to create a login route/action that will handle all your authorize requests:

```cs
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [MyCustomAuthorize]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            returnUrl = Session["oidc-returnUrl"]?.ToString();

            // clean up
            Session["oidc-returnUrl"] = null;

            return Redirect(returnUrl ?? "/");
        }
    }
}
```

The login path can be changed in your startup code:

```cs
public class Startup
{

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = "/my-login"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            // setting up your client
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your sample, thank you! The last part for configuration is outdated for core 2. The configuration should be done on Services rather on app. I'll give it a try. Thanks for you time.